# Adding a Reference to System.Web

Tags: reference

I am trying to create some cookies as I cannot fetch the cookies and a normal way so I will run through the whole header and just create the cookie manually. However whenever I try to use `Response.Cookies` and `HttpCookie` I get an error:

> The name Response does not exist in the current content

and

> The type or namespace name 'HttpCookie' could not be found (are you missing a using  directive or an assembly reference?).

I read around and understood I will need to reference

```
System.Web
```

So I am clicking on `Project -> Add Reference -> .NET` and select `System.Web`.  Then I add `using System.Web;`.

And still I am unable to access them.

Comment: After you add the reference, what errors are you getting?

Comment: I am getting the exact same error, as if i did not add the reference

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what code are you trying to access the item?

There are essentially two steps that need to be taken to reference a class:

1. Add a reference to the class' assembly in the project.
2. Add a `using` directive to the class' namespace in the code file.

It sounds like you're performed the first step.  What about the second?  That's what this error means:

> The type or namespace name 'HttpCookie' could not be found (are you missing a using  directive or an assembly reference?).

To perform step 2 above, you actually have a couple of options:

1. Fully-qualify the class name.  So, instead of using `HttpCookie` you would use `System.Web.HttpCookie`.
2. Add a `using` directive to the code file.  At the top of the file (and this would need to be done for any file which uses classes in this namespace), you would add `using System.Web`.  Then you could just reference `HttpCookie` directly.

Additionally, the first part of your question brings up a separate issue entirely:

> The name Response does not exist in the current context

This again goes back to my question about where you're accessing this value.  When you're writing code in, say, the code-behind for an ASPX page, you have access to the various bits of ASP.NET web contexts by default.  These are provided by the base `Page` class.  Things like `Request` and `Response` are readily available.

However, if you're trying to access these objects from outside of that context (such as from a custom class or another assembly), you'll need to reference that context manually.  This can be done by using a factory on [the `System.Web.HttpContext` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.aspx):

1. `Request` becomes `System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request`
2. `Response` becomes `System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response`

This is because `Request` and `Response` aren't actual classes.  They're properties on the current web context which are of type `HttpRequest` and `HttpResponse`.  Those properties are mapped for you when you're in the same context, but outside of that context you'd need to reference them fully as demonstrated above.

One thing to note is that it's not generally considered good practice to have dependencies on the web context outside of where it's already available.  So if you're creating a custom class or another assembly then you might want to take a step back and think about the design.

If your custom classes depend on the existence of a current instance of `HttpContext` then that code can never be used outside of a fully-aware web application context.  So the code is less re-usable.  So, depending on what you need from that context, you can re-factor the code to not need the context itself but only to require that the necessary items from the context be provided.

This isn't necessary to get you past your current issue, but it's something to keep in mind going forward.

Comment: So as you probably understood i am a novice Visual studio user, i basically learn as i try stuff, my current project is to log to a website in a click of a button. so i have the code to do it in the button.  About HttpCookie its seem i've already fixed it with the reference and using system.web - its seems to be working, though about request / reqsones they both arent working unless i use your "System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request" and "System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Respones" so the problem seem to be solved however i dont know how i am accessing them

Comment: @YanivKossas: That's fine.  New developers are certainly welcome at Stack Overflow.  We value one's ability to ask a coherent question above one's ability to find the solution.  While there's certainly a language barrier, I think your question was fairly clear.  The main issue you were having was that you weren't interpreting the error messages correctly, and that comes only from experience.

Comment: Basically i just opened a window document and started working from there so i am not sure from where i am accessing it. I will try and use the above help you gave me and if i will stumble upon a new problem i will search for a solution then.

Comment: @YanivKossas: I'm not sure what you mean by "a window document."  Are you working inside of Visual Studio?  Generally the process for creating something new in Visual Studio is `File->New->Project` where you choose the project type and where to save it.  Then you'd primarily add new things from the `Solution Explorer` window.  For example, to add a new class to the project, you'd right click on the project name or the folder within the project where you want to add it and select `Add->New Item` and choose the item type.  To get you started, you might want to look for tutorials or books.

Comment: That is exactly what i did, file -> new -> project and window form application. well from my previous experience with C and php reading from books is nice but not a good learning way, seem i get things better if i try them.

Comment: @YanivKossas: A "Windows Forms" application?  If you're developing a Windows Forms application then you won't have cookies or a web context of any kind.  As part of your research you'll want to look into the difference between local applications (Windows Forms, WPF, etc.) and web application (Web Forms, MVC, WCF, etc.).  The two variations are _vastly_ different architectures.

Comment: yea i will look into web Form - this is my first project though - will learn in time. There is some message popped not to extend discussions in comments so i will click to move this to chat

Comment: David you mean that from windows form i cannot use HttpWebrequest to connect to a website then send the parameters in POST and retrieve the cookies ? will i have to use something else ?

Comment: @YanivKossas: I guess it's not clear what you're trying to do. I was under the impression that you were writing a web application and needed to interact with cookies from that perspective. If you're writing a client application then you can internally interact with a web application (though you'll probably want to use `System.Net.WebRequest` instead), though I don't know how you'd handle the cookies it uses.

Comment: have been at this for 2 weeks now :-) every day i learn something new, i will eventually achieve what i am trying and then move to another project i am clueless about. What i was trying to do is have a button and once i click this button i log into a website and continue browsing this website using the cookies i got as a response. i so far managed everything except the cookies handling which seem to be the hardest part.